# Filepond removeFiles seems not to be working

Tags: filepond

Calling removeFiles on a filepond instance object, seems to only remove the first file and not all of them.

(Which would be the expected behaviour for calling removeFile (singular) without parameters )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. [Docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#methods) says, that it's has an argument:[query], and no information about usage of empty args.

I found in [Changelog 4.19.0](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/blob/d1dd6dbfb6259d51c77bf07a9f1e0d33c1d90777/CHANGELOG.md#4190) message about fixing problem: `removeFiles({ revert: false })`. So I tried this snippet, and it cleaned all images. I don't think that is the correct usage of `{ revert: false }`, but it solves the problem.